# Overloading method on extended class

Tags: java

Simple question, strange result. I have two classes `A` and `B`:

```
public class A
{
    protected int num;

    public A(int n)
    {
        num = n;
    }

    public boolean f(A a)
    {
        return num == a.num * 2;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class B extends A
{
    public B(int n)
    {
        super(n);
    }

    public boolean f(B b)
    {
        return num == b.num;
    }
}
```

Why does `y1.f(y2)` call the `f()` method in `A` instead of in `B`?

```
A y1 = new B(10);
B y2 = new B(10);

System.out.println(y1.f(y2));
```

Is it not supposed to call `f()` in `B` as `B` is more specific than `A`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Why does y1.f(y2) calls the f() method in A instead of in B?

Because the compile-time type of `y1` is `A`.

Overloading is performed at *compile-time*... the execution-time type of the object you call the method on is only relevant for *overriding*.

So the compiler is choosing the method `f(A)` as that's the only `f` method it's aware it can call on `y1` (and it's checked that it's applicable given the argument list). That method isn't overridden in `B`, therefore at execution time, the implmenetation in `A` is called.

As a starker example, consider this code:

```
Object x = "foo";
int length = x.length();
```

This won't even compile, because `Object` doesn't contain a `length()` method. `String` does, but the compiler doesn't consider that, because the compile-time type of `x` is `Object`, not `String` - even though we can tell that at execution time, the value of `x` will be a reference to a `String` object.

Comment: Though @JonSkeet's answer are always unquestionable .. Just Supporting this with Byte code too .. you can also check what method is getting passed and you can see that for

compiled code `(y1.f(y2))` when you see byte code  

 `25: invokevirtual #27                 // Method com/package1/A.f:(Lcom/p
ackage1/A;)Z`